# How to apply a customized function to a list of urls?

Tags: python, function, web-scraping

### Update

I am trying to define a function for a list of urls, the function is intended to print either if a certain link or a server is not found from the original list (`job_title_links`):

This is what I've got so far:

```
from urllib.error import URLError
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.request import urlopen

job_title_links =['https://www.salario.com.br/profissao/abacaxicultor-cbo-612510/',
                  'https://www.salario.com.br/profissao/abade-cbo-263105/',
                  'https://www.salario.com.br/profissao/abanador-na-agricultura-cbo-622020/']

def try_url_exist(links):
    for link in job_title_links:
      try:
       html=urlopen(link)
      except HTTPError as e:
        print(e)         #  not found url
      except URLError as e: 
        print(e)         # server not found


try_url_exist(job_title_links)
```

However the function returns me a list of `HTTPError 403` even when the
url's exist.

Console output:

```
HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Expected function output should do nothing if the url exists and should return
either `HTTPError` or `URLError` and the name of the url when the url does not exist.

How could I accomplish this task?

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace, we can't see where this error is happening.

Comment: It seems like your are not authorized to view these pages

Answer (score 0):

By changing `urlopen()` to `requests.get()` from `requests` library and adding it
to an empty list, the code worked.

```
import requests
from urllib.error import URLError
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.request import urlopen


def try_url_exist(links):
    for link in job_title_links:
      try:
        html=requests.get(link)
      except HTTPError as e:
        print(e)       
      except URLError as e: 
        print(e)        
      else:
        print(link)
         
      
functional_links = []
functional_links = try_url_exist(job_title_links)
```

Comment: However definitely this code could be optimized.

Comment: Using headers within `urllib.request.Request()` and then `urllib.request.urlopen()` should fix the issue that you were having in the first place.